# How to install old mysql 5.6 to ubuntu 18

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I followed https://makandracards.com/makandra/39899-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-16-04  this guide to point where i use `apt update`.

I need mysql 5.6 server and client tools since software that i am using is not working with latest one...

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu wily InRelease: The following si                                                                                                                                                             gnatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mys                                                                                                                                                             ql-build@oss.oracle.com> A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu wily InRelease' is not sign                                                                                                                                                             ed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                                                             ils.
```

How to disable cant be done securely think?

Comment: Older releases require older operating system versions. You may want to look at using a [containerized version](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead.